# What do rodents do?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, etymology, vocabulary

I wonder if there is a English verb to express the way rodents (rats, mice, etc.) bite on something they are trying to eat or bite.

In Portuguese we have the verb *roer* which comes from *roedor* which means rodent and this also applies to other animals that are biting through some hard material for either eating it or not (pencil tips ring to mind). I'm curious to know if English has a similar word.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I believe [*gnaw*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gnaw) is the word you're looking for.

> a :  to bite or chew on with the teeth; especially :  to wear away by persistent biting or nibbling 
>   b :  to make by gnawing <rats gnawed a hole>

Comment: MW - 1b) to make by gnawing *rats gnawed a hole*.

Comment: [gnawer](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/gnawer) = rodent

Comment: "Nah, they don't!" "Gnaw, they do!"

Comment: In many European languages, rodents are defined by that which they do. French: rongeur, ronger; German: Nagetier, nagen, Dutch: knaagdier, knagen etc. English seems to be an exception.

Comment: What I want to know is how the `g` became silent.

Comment: @Gabe If you want to know that, you should ask a new question. And it's not just the `g`; The `k` suffers too.

Comment: @MrLister The English word is also derived from what they do; it comes from the Latin _rodere_. It's just that we use a different word to actually describe what they do, the Anglo-Saxon _gnaw_.

Answer (score 26):

The ultimate font of all these words, including both English *rodent* and Portuguese *roer*, is the classical Latin (and also modern Italian) verb ***rodere/rodo***, which in English means ***“to gnaw or corrode”***.

To elaborate somewhat upon the most simple and direct answer, let’s look at what a couple thousand years of hungry rodents gnawing away at our languages have produced.

---

### *Of Mice and Muribus*

Although compared with the incorrodible classical Latin form, the Italian version hasn’t been gnawed upon at all due to the temerity of Italian mice, in French we find that it’s slightly corroded to just *roder* instead.

However, down in Iberia where the mice are fiercer, and especially in Portugal whose mice are the fiercest of all Romance mice, it’s eroded even further down to just *roer* in both Spanish and Portuguese.

But that’s not all. The Iberian mice have chewed off thoroughly irregular portions of nearly all the inflections of this verb there:

- Spanish has the infinitive *roer* go to a regular *roo* or to either of the equally irregular *roigo* or *royo* in the present indicative (nobody can make up their minds which of the three to use) and hence has irregular present subjunctives all the way down if you’re in the 2nd or 3rd camp; preterite 1sg *roí* but irregular 3sg *royó* and hence irregular *royese* etc. in the imperfect subjunctive; irregular past participle *roído* and irregular gerund *royendo*.
- Portuguese has infinitive *roer* become in the present 1sg *roo* (or irregular *rôo* in Brazil) but irregular 2sg *róis, 3sg rói*; irregular preterite 1sg *roí*; irregular past participle *roído*.

As you see, many of those inflections have been quite irregularly “gnawed upon” by the indigenous Iberian “gnawers” — that is, by their “rodents”.

Meanwhile in the east of Iberia over in Catalunya, things somehow took a slightly different turn when Latin *rodere/rodo* mutated into the somewhat more exotic form, a Vulgar Latin *rosicare* derived instead from *rosus*, the present active participle of *rodere/rodo*.

And so the Catalans, having milder mice than most of Iberia but nonetheless subjected to the erosive forces of history, produced from that putative Vulgar Latin form the almost surprisingly regular *rosegar* as the verb and *rosegars* for the gnawsome critters themselves — or the slightly more chewed-upon *rosegaires* for their northerly Occitan/Provençal cousins.

---

Lest it were less than obvious from my agnawing diversion above, the English words that share the same common Latin-derived element include not only the obvious ***rodent*** as one who gnaws, but also things like ***corrode*** and ***erode***, plus all their derived forms. Something that it *corrosive* gnaws away at something else, as *erosion* gnaws away at the terra firma until it is much less firma. :)

In sum, the only words I could find in English that derive from Latin *rodere* directly or indirectly are 
*anticorrosion, corrodability, corrodable, corrode, corroded, corrodent,
corroder, corrodiary, corrodiating, corrodibility, corrodible, corrodier,
corroding, corrody, corrosibility, corrosible, corrosibleness, corrosion,
corrosive, corrosively, corrosiveness, corrosiving, corrosivity, erodable,
erode, eroded, erodent, eroding, erose, erosion, erosional, erosionist,
erosive, erosive, eroso-, incorrodible, incorrosive, rodent, rodential,
rodentially, rodentian*, and — alas! — *rodenticidal* and *rodenticide*.

They’re all of them about gnawing, one way or the other.

Comment: hah! beautifully written! +1 for you, sir

Comment: Oh my... What have I done!? :-) +1 for great style!!!

Comment: Perhaps cor+rode = gnaw at the heart of . . .

Comment: @DavidM Actually, it was the intensifying prefix *com-* which assimilated to *cor-*, so Latin *corrodere* (and perhaps also our own *corrode*) means “to gnaw way at”.

Comment: I figured not. Just seemed like a cute coincidence.  Fascinating answer - BTW.

Comment: I.. i.. never realized *corrosão* (corrosion), *erosão* (erosion) and *roer* (gnaw) had the same Latin origin (*rodere*) .. It looks so obvious now

Comment: I'm surprised you didn't manage to work in `rot`.

Comment: Upvoted for a fun writeup, but I believe all of those Portuguese forms you mention are actually regular. The vowel-final stem demands some disambiguating accent marks in writing that are unnecessary with the more common consonant-final ones. The _roo_ vs. _rôo_ is just a spelling reform with no difference in pronunciation (like _voo_ vs. _vôo_).

Comment: @hemflit I thought about distinguishing orthographic irregulars from phonologic ones, but then decided it wasn’t worth getting into. That one must write *roído* is irregular in spelling but perfectly normal to the ear.

Comment: @tchrist I know I'm discussing a footnote to a footnote here, but I really wouldn't think of it as an orthographic irregularity. It's a result of regular, general rules of Portuguese spelling, differentiating the ⟨oí⟩ /ɔˈiː/ and ⟨ói⟩ /ˈɔi/ from ⟨oi⟩ /ˈoj/. The same rules are seen at work in corresponding forms of _doer_ and _moer_. The only reason they're not seen more often is that most verbs have a consonant-letter there that already does the job.

Comment: I had never given much thought to the etymology of **rodent** but had always assumed it was connected with **dent** = teeth (a distinguishing feature of rodents being that there teeth grow continuously). So I am glad to have learned something new here!

Answer (score 11):

By etymology, *rodent* is a Latin participle of the verb *rodere* (to gnaw).