# What is the origin of "rat"?

Tags: etymology, origin-unknown, animals

A simple little word for a common little fella. Yet, the origin is unknown (*or not?*).

Both *OED* and *Etymonline* are bold enough to say "of uncertain origin"; but, of course, they try to explain the etymology of *rat* with *Latin, Romanic, Germanic, Celtic and Greek* connections.

[*Etymonline*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=cat&allowed_in_frame=0) summarizes in the first paragraph as follows:

> late Old English *ræt* "rat," of uncertain origin. Similar words are found in Celtic (Gaelic *radan*), Romanic (Italian *ratto*, Spanish *rata*, French *rat*) and Germanic (Old Saxon *ratta*; Dutch *rat*; German *Ratte*, dialectal *Ratz*; Swedish *råtta*, Danish *rotte*) languages, but connection is uncertain and origin unknown. In all this it is very much like *[cat](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=cat&allowed_in_frame=0)*.

<sub><sup>*(a hint for the next question: cat!)*</sup></sub>

*Etymonline* gives its own opinion also and includes the dispute between big names:

> - Perhaps from Vulgar Latin * *rattus*

- **Weekley** thinks this is of Germanic origin, "the animal having come from the East with the race-migrations" and the word passing thence to the Romanic languages
- **American Heritage and Tucker** connect Old English *ræt* to Latin *rodere* and thus PIE * *red-* "to scrape, scratch, gnaw," source of *[rodent](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=rodent&allowed_in_frame=0)* (q.v.).
- **Klein** says there is no such connection and suggests a possible cognate in Greek *rhine* "file, rasp."
- **Weekley** connects them with a question mark and **Barnhart** writes, "the relationship to each other of the Germanic, Romance, and Celtic words for *rat* is uncertain.
- **OED** says "probable" the rat word spread from Germanic to Romanic, but takes no position on ultimate origin.

The connection to the origin of *rodent* (Latin *rodere* "to gnaw, eat away," from PIE root *red-*) stands out but not favored by *Klein* and *OED* and it is mentioned as an uncertain connection.  
<sup>(Related question: [What do rodents do?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/156079/what-do-rodents-do/156085#156085))</sup>

*[OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/158382?rskey=GBkPbG&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid)* goes deeper into the rathole and gives a detailed etymology; and includes the following reasons for the uncertainty:

> - It is uncertain whether the Latin and Romance words are cognate with the Germanic words, or whether they were borrowed from Germanic, or vice versa; **in any case the ultimate origin is uncertain; perhaps imitative of the sound of gnawing.**

- None of the Latin and Romance words is attested before the end of the first millennium, and the fact that the German word has not undergone the High German sound shift suggests that the Germanic group is also late (Middle High German *ratz , ratze* , German regional (chiefly southern) *Ratz , Ratze* are secondary, perhaps hypocoristic formations).
- The word was probably spread with the reintroduction of rats to Northern Europe during the Viking Age (for a discussion of the physical evidence compare P. L. Armitage in Antiquity 68 (1994) 231–40).
- A derivation < an ablaut variant of the Indo-European base of classical Latin *rōdere* to gnaw (see rodent adj.) has been suggested, but seems unlikely in the light of the apparently recent introduction of the word.
- A suggested derivation of the Romance words < classical Latin *rapidus* rapid adj. is no longer accepted, as it would only account for the Italian, which for chronological and historical reasons cannot be the single origin of the whole group.

But, I didn't stop ratting there and checked historical records that include the word "rat" and found the oldest etymological and lexical references as follows:

From ["An universal etymological English dictionary"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVczQ.png) *By Nathan Bailey* (1731):

> a RAT [rat, F. ratta, Span. ratze, Teut. ratte, Du.] an amphibious kind of Animal, infesting Houses, Ships, &c.

<sub>[*(obsolete)* Teut. -> Teutonic -> Germanic]</sub>

From "[A dictionary of the English language](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFqOY.png) : in which the words are deduced from their originals, and illustrated in their different significations by examples from the best writers : to which are prefixed, a history of the language, and an English grammar"
*By Samuel Johnson* (1766):

> RAT. f. [ratte, Dutch; rat, French; ratta, Spanish.] An animal of the mouse kind that infests houses and ships

And the rat-hunting went on an' on and I ended up with the *[brown rat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_rat)* (and its etymological origin) which is one of the best known and most common rat. It is named *Rattus norvegicus* (Norwegian rat) which is a misnomer because the English naturalist John Berkenhout gave the binomial name, believing it had migrated to England from Norwegian ships in 1728 (which is disproven later.)

Towards the end of 19th century, the etymology of *brown rat* was better understood and the following note is mentioned in "Natural History" *by American scholar Alfred Henry Miles*:

> The brown rat is the species common in England, and best known throughout the world. **It is said to have travelled from Persia to England less than two hundred years ago** and to have spread from thence to other countries visited by English ships

This finding gives a hint that the origin of the word *rat* might be of *Persian* origin (and also *Sanskrit*) [[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rat) puts as "Middle Persian *randītan* (“to scrape, smooth”), Sanskrit *rádati* (“he gnaws, cuts”))."]

Also mentioned in "The Oxford Introduction to Proto-Indo-European and the Proto-Indo-European World" *By J. P. Mallory, D. Q. Adams*:

> The Engligh *rat* takes its name from **red*- 'gnaw, scrape' (cf. also Lat *rōdō* 'gnaw', MPers *randītan* 'scrape, smooth', Skt *rádati* 'bites, gnaws, cuts, makes way, opens').

However, the *brown rat* ultimately came from central Asia and (likely) China. The pinyin *shǔ* of Han character 鼠 (rat) in Mandarin doesn't evoke anything, though I'm like a rat in a corner at this point. [Although, Sanskrit and Mandarin are from the same geographical region.)

In conclusion, *Persian* and *Sanskrit* origin makes sense and it wouldn't be possible to go further back (unless a *Hittite* origin? *Rats!*).

Anything more to add? Is it possible to find further clarification?

<sub><sup>Sorry, I couldn't think of a fancy title for the question.</sup></sub>

Comment: Well the Japanese certainly don't say *rat*, so it can't have come from there. They say *nezumi* and have no separate word for *mouse*. There are big *nezumi* and small *nezumi*.

Comment: @WS2 that's certainly interesting but do you know anything about when rats reached Japan? After all it's an island nation that has at various times in its history chosen to cut itself off to some extent from other countries and therefore their shipping.

Comment: @ChrisH I have no idea. Perhaps from China, whose traders took  to the Japanese the influence of their language and writing system - perhaps rats came as part of the package!

Comment: @WS2 perhaps. I ask because if "mouse" and "rat" share a word in Japanese, and mice were common before rats arrived, calling the new pest a "big mouse" would be sensible. It wouldn't have much benefit to linguists though. This pattern of naming a newly-encountered species after a familiar one is perhaps more common in the colonisation of the new world -- "elk", "sparrow" etc.

Comment: Wikipedia isn't much help here. But they have an entry on *nezumi* which confirms that the Kanji character is, as I suspected it would be, exactly the same as the OP's Chinese character for *rat*. Apparently the *brown rat* originated in northern China, and has now spread to every continent.

Comment: I infer from the etymological equivocation that rats may have originated in England and spread throughout the world from there. We really wouldn't want to document that shameful chapter in our history, would we? If the rats came with the Brits, there are two possibilities: they just used the English word rat, or they corrupted Brits into rats. Another possibility is that Adam called them rats in the garden, and the name just stuck--for the most part. All my Japanese friends say rat, when they talk to me.

Comment: The OED/etymonline explanation is frustrating because it doesn't say _why_ the origin/connection is uncertain (because it is so obviously connected with the Latin). Presumably the doubt is because of inconsistent sound change trajectories. Except that the Romance and Germanic languages _all_ have very close to 'rattus' in their modern versions. If The OED is saying 'unknown' for this word, then they should be saying it for quite a few other similar very common words with well-attested etymologies.

Comment: Actually, the origin of the term goes back to 1012, during the reign of AEthiered the Unready.  A cook for the royal court walked into the royal bakery to discover rodents gnawing on the massive cake that had been created for the evening's festivities.  As he picked up a pot to throw at the animals he yelled "RATTUS!!", an old Welch-Yiddish term meaning "goldarnit".  And the name stuck.

Comment: Hi @Laurel, you recently deleted two pictures in this post and transcribed the words displayed in the pictures. You changed the long s in "infefting" to a "c", so that the new word was "infecting". I would assume that this should be "infesting" except that you did it twice (the second time changing "infefts" to "infects"). Was that intentional? (All other long s's were changed to short s's.)

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Typos, sorry (the pictures are still linked just in case).

Comment: After reading the question and all the answers and comments, I think it safe to say that the origin of "rat" is uncertain.

Comment: "Sanskrit and Mandarin are from the same geographical region" if you consider NE China and Persia to be the same geographical region. I don't think that's sufficient to infer a strong connection.

Answer (score 4):

In Old Norse, [Ratatoskr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratatoskr) means "drill-tooth" or "bore-tooth". It is the name of a mythical creature,  a squirrel that runs up and down the tree of life called Yggdrasil, acting as a messenger between two arch enemies: the great eagle and the terrestrial dragon.

> According to Albert Sturtevant, "[as] far as the element ***Rata***- is concerned, Bugge's hypothesis has no valid foundation in view of the fact that the [Old Norse] word *Rata* (gen. form of *Rati**) is used in *Háv[amál]* to signify **the instrument which Odin employed for boring his way through the rocks in quest of the poet's mead** [...]" and that "*Rati** must then be considered a native [Old Norse] word meaning "The Borer, Gnawer"
>
> <sub>Wikipedia</sub>

One can therefore assume that the word rat stems from a description of its behaviour.

Comment: Do you have a reference for that Old Norse definition, and any evidence that it also applies to English?

Answer (score 2):

On the Isle of Man a rat was known by the term 'queer fellow' , a very old saying and one l don't know whether  is still in use. It was often used alongside the word 'frickened'.

Comment: Your name is strangely appropriate for this answer.

Comment: @JATerroba "There is no shortage of superstitions on the Isle of Man. One of them is that if you are Manx, you do not use the word - RAT" [transceltic.com](https://www.transceltic.com/blog/manx-and-never-using-three-letter-r-word-vermin)

Answer (score 2):

Another conjecture:

> Cp. Span. *ratón* 'mouse', *rata* 'rat, Gasc. *arrat* 'rat', Bq.
> *arratu* 'rat'. The word occurs only in Romance, Germanic, and Celtic and is of unknown origin. It may be a Vasconic loan-word that was lost
> in Basque when the constraint against in initial rhotics arose. Bq.
> *arrautu* etc. were borrowed from Romance, with obligatory  prosthesis because of the constraint. However, since the rat is an immigrant from
> East and South-East Asia (*Der Große Brockhaus*: s.v. *Ratten*), its
> European name too may have Asian roots. [Theo Vennemann Nierfeld et
> al.; *Europa Vasconica, Europa Semitica*](https://books.google.com/books?id=tyU1FymabrgC&pg=PA704&lpg=PA704&dq=vasconic%20%22arratu%22&source=bl&ots=sM2-IwjP3z&sig=ACfU3U369cwbzt3llBlg92el198ue_vicg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjJxKuYs9T0AhUdonIEHbOsBu8Q6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=vasconic%20%22arratu%22&f=false) p.704, footenote 30
> (2003)

Comment: Whenever the trail goes dead, somebody always blames the Basques. :) Curious indeed that Ancient Latin and Ancient Greek both lacked any dedicated term for a rat that wasn't just a big mouse. The [OED3 now sports a rather long ramble on the etymology](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/158382) that goes a bit further than quickly blaming the millennial Vikings and leaving the matter there, but it’s still a far candle from [these more recent investigations](https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/2021.04.14.439553v1.full).

Comment: @tchrist Thanks, I'll basque in the warm glow of the ancient genomes.

Comment: It is great to see another possible route that involves Vasconic languages and Basque. The passage concludes with a similar finding in my post that it might have Asian roots. Congrats for the bounty. I've upvoted also.

Comment: Spanish *ratón* 'mouse', *rata* 'rat' is also slightly odd in that *-ón* is often an augmentative suffix, not a diminutive.  Both displaced the Old Spanish *mur* from Classical Latin *mus*

Answer (score -2):

It may be that we would have to look for a paraphrase or a two-word expression, e.g. "great mouse". Just a vague idea for Latin: "mus + cretus" ( mouse + grown big).
Perhaps one has not found more information about the origin because the idea is a word must be one word historically. That a lot of words were at first multi-word explanations that were shortened in the course of time and became a single word at the end is often not taken into consideration.

Comment: Huh? Are you proposing that "rattus" is derived from "mus cretus"? That seems completely random.

Comment: Would it be so astonishing that a lot of one-part words have their origin in simple two-part paraphrases that in the course of time were melted into a one-part word?

Comment: The astonishing part is more that you just threw this out there. To do serious etymology work, it would be necessary to look at the history: do we have any examples of the *phrase* "mus cretus" ever used in Latin to refer to rats? Is there evidence of any intermediate forms, like "muscretus" or "muscratus"? Are there any other words that show a parallel shift of "e" to "a" and "t" to "tt"? If you have no answer to any of these, why do you expect anyone to be convinced by your proposed etymology?

Comment: I spoke of a vague idea to show that a two-part paraphrase might be to consider. I did not say that mus cretus is the origin of rat. A lot of other paraphrases might be possible.

Comment: OK... that's true, and I'm sorry that I've been commenting from the position that this is an actual proposed etymology; if I understand right, it's more of an example of a possible way words can derive. In that case, I think it would be better if you just removed the part about "mus cretus" entirely and replaced it with an example of another word, one that is known to have derived from a two-word phrase. It doesn't have to be related to "rat."  As it is, I find this answer possibly misleading (I'd worry about someone taking "mus cretus" seriously), and that's the main reason I downvoted.

Comment: Okay. I understand your problem. But at the moment I have no convincing examples that could explain my long-time theory that a lot of words have their origin in multipart paraphrases that in the course of time were shortened and finally became one word. Etymology can only look at earlier one-part forms.  But I'm beginning to collect examples that could give an idea that basically paraphrases are a normal way for the creation of words.

Comment: It's too bad this can't work as the origin of 'muskrat'.